# Maya Python: Undo becomes unavailable after using undoInfo()

Tags: python, maya, qt-designer, pyside2

I've created a tool in Maya that takes values from currently selected objects, does some modifications to them and gives them back.I also have a simple gui window(made in QtDesigner if it makes sense),which has a QSlider and I pass values by dragging this slider. So, everything was working fine and I thought that it's completely ready for using but some problems with undo appeared. So, below in the **init** method I do this

```
        super(winMain, self).__init__()
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load(ui_path, self)
        self.slider_released = self.ui.slider.sliderReleased
```

I have more code written in here it's just not connected to this. Below is the actionCaller() function where I call the action() function(this just does some math and generates values that should be passed to objects).

```
def actionCaller(self, some_value):
        cmds.undoInfo(openChunk=True, infinity=True)
        while not self.slider_released:
            continue
        else:
            self.action(some_value)
        cmds.undoInfo(closeChunk=True)
```

So I want to pass sliders value(some_value) only when it's released and therefor I added cmds.undoInfo() method for undoing the whole process as a one undo. Everything works fine while I use my program, only when I try to undo actions I've done before executing my code Maya gives this error:

```
// Error: line 1: Undo is temporarily unavailable.  Try exiting the current tool.
```

I think that maya somehow gets in the while loop that I wrote above and undo queue becomes unavailable. Maybe I'm wrong idk. Can someone please tell me what the problem could be in here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are 3 important problems with that code: 1. `sliderReleased` is a *signal*, it doesn't return a value, it should be connected to a function that acts when the signal is emitted (in that case, only *when* the slider is released); 2. using that as a condition in a while loop won't work as it's just an object used for connections (it's like doing `while not self.someFunction:`); 3. even if that worked, while loops are blocking, and prevent proper event handling, so they should never be used in a main UI function unless you're completely sure that they exit as soon as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Maya so I cannot really help you with this, and it's also unclear how/when that `actionCaller` is actually triggered. If you need to do some computation only when the slider is released, then you should *connect* to that signal to a function that actually calls your action with the current slider value. Something like `self.ui.slider.sliderReleased.connect(self.callAction)` and then `self.action(self.ui.slider.value())` in that `callAction` function.

Comment: Hi @musicamante ! Thank you for you response. I think I messed up my code a little. Your code looks cleaner. I will try it out and let you know:)

Answer (score 0):

Comments section is not comfortable for posting code so I'm doing it here.

@musicamante using sliderReleased as a condition was actually a bad idea, so doing what you suggested helped. I modified the code a little bit and now it looks like this and everything works as expected:

```
self.ui.slider.sliderReleased.connect(self.actionCaller)
```

and

```
def actionCaller(self, slider_value):
        cmds.undoInfo(openChunk=True, infinity=True)
        try:
            while not True:
                continue
            else:
                self.action(slider_value)
        finally:
            cmds.undoInfo(closeChunk=True)
```

Thanks for your help:)